# Multiplayer doesn't work with other computers. Only on the same one

Tags: c#, tcp, server, client

The title says it already. I have a tcp listener and you can access it with ipadress.any. But when i test it on other computers my connection doesn't work. Here is my server code:

```
namespace AsyncClientServer
{


public class Server
{
    public TcpListener Listener;
    private volatile bool Running; //wordt gebruikt door meerdere threads zonder lock te gebruiken (lock zorgt ervoor dat een thread niet doorgaat naar belangrijke code terwjil een andere thread nog bezig is om naar de locked code te gaan.
    private List<BinaryWriter> writers = new List<BinaryWriter>();
    bool playerCount = false;
    public Server(int port)
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Listener.Start(10);
        Running = true;

        while (Running)
        {
            var connection = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ProcessConnection(connection);
        }
    }


    public async Task ProcessConnection(TcpClient connection)
    { 
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(connection.GetStream());

        lock (writers)
        {
            writers.Add(writer);
        }

        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(connection.GetStream()))
        {
            //hvlheid connectie
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(writers.Count));
                playerCount = true;
                ProcessCommand(connection, writer, data);
            });
            //loop 
            while (Running && connection.Connected)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    var count = stream.ReadInt32();
                    var data = stream.ReadBytes(count);
                    ProcessCommand(connection, writer, data);
                });
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        lock (writers)
        {
            writers.Remove(writer);
        }
    }


    private void ProcessCommand(TcpClient connection, BinaryWriter writer, byte[] data)
    {
        //var info = connection.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        if (playerCount)
        {
            playerCount = false;
            lock (writers)
            {
                foreach (var w in writers)
                {
                    if (w != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            w.Write((Int32)data.Length);
                            w.Write(data);
                            w.Flush();
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //var line = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            //var response = String.Format("{1}:{2}: {0}", line, info.Address.ToString(), info.Port);
            //Console.WriteLine(response);
            lock (writers)
            {
                foreach (var w in writers)
                {
                    if (w != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            w.Write((Int32)data.Length);
                            w.Write(data);
                            w.Flush();
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        Listener.Stop();
    }
    ~Server()
    {
        Running = false;
        Listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

program.cs:

```
     public static class MainClass
    {
        public static readonly int Port = 5000;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new Server(Port);
            server.Start();
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
     Start(5000);
 public async Task Start(int port)
    {

        Connection.Connect("localhost", port);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        Running = true;
        Writer = new BinaryWriter(Connection.GetStream());

        using (var stream = new BinaryReader(Connection.GetStream()))
        {
            //infinite loop
            while (Running && Connection.Connected)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    var count = stream.ReadInt32();
                    var data = stream.ReadBytes(count);
                    ProcessCommand(data);
                });
            }
            Stop();
        }
    }
    //send player coordinates naar server
    int[] temporary = new int[4];

    public async Task Coordinates()
    {
        if (Client1)
        {
            temporary[0] = (int)Player1_x;
            temporary[1] = (int)Player1_y;
        }
        else
        {
            temporary[2] = (int)Player2_x;
            temporary[3] = (int)Player2_y;
        }
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //send player 1 coordinates naar server
                var player_coordinates = new byte[temporary.Length * sizeof(int) + sizeof(bool) + sizeof(bool)];
                //zet coordinates in de byte array
                Buffer.BlockCopy(temporary, 0, player_coordinates, 0, temporary.Length * sizeof(int));
                //zet collision in de byte array
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Collision_player1), 0, player_coordinates, temporary.Length * sizeof(int), sizeof(bool));
                Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Collision_player2), 0, player_coordinates, temporary.Length * sizeof(int) + sizeof(bool), sizeof(bool));
                Writer.Write((Int32)player_coordinates.Length);
                Writer.Write(player_coordinates);
                Writer.Flush();
            });
    }
    //send data voor chat
    public async Task Send(String line)
    {
        if (Writer == null)
            return;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
            Writer.Write((Int32)data.Length);
            Writer.Write(data);
            Writer.Flush();
        });
    }

    //krijg het aantal spelers connected
    private void ProcessCommand(byte[] data)
    {
        if (players)
        {
            var playerCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            PlayerCountMethod(Convert.ToInt32(playerCount));
            if (playerCount == "1") {
                Client1 = true;
            }
            else if (playerCount == "2")
            {
                players = false;
            }

        } else
        {
            if (Client1)
            {
                Player2_x = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 2 * sizeof(int));
                Player2_y = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 3 * sizeof(int));
            } else
            {
                Player1_x = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                Player1_y = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, sizeof(int));
            }
            //
            if (Collision_player1 == false)
            {
                Collision_player1 = BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, temporary.Length * sizeof(int));
            }
            //
            if (Collision_player2 == false)
            {
                Collision_player2 = BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, temporary.Length * sizeof(int) + sizeof(bool));
            }

            //try-catch want anders argument out of range als er geen message wordt gestuurd
            //try
            //{
            //    var line = BitConverter.ToString(data, temporary.Length * sizeof(int));
            //    ////stuur data van server naar method
            //    textboxChat(line);
            //}
            //catch
            //{

            //}
        }

    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        Writer.Close();
        Writer = null;
        Connection.Close();

    }
    ~GamePlay()
    {
        Stop();
    }
```

Its probably a realy easy mistake, but i don't know why it works when i open multiple program's on my pc. But it doesn't work when i open it on other pc's.

Comment: Does your computer have a firewall running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following line of code:

```
Connection.Connect("localhost", port);
```

If you try to execute this on another machine it will look for an open socket on the request port *on the same machine*

Comment: Moments like these make me question my existence.

Comment: What should i change it too ? :P In my defence i am not a pro programmer, just a student starting out. The initial server-client connection is from github. I changed a lot, but i still don't know how everything works lol

Comment: It needs to be the IP address of where the server is running, preferably in a config somewhere.

Comment: Either the IP address or host name of the machine where the listener was setup

Comment: You need your public IP address and the port where your Server is listening. And after setting it, you'll probably need to configure your router firewall to allow income requests to that ip:port. (probably responses from ip:port too)

Comment: By the way, you are using Port:5000. You just need to find your public IP which you may get by writing on google: "what's my ip", and click on the first link.

Comment: @LeandroSoares That almost certainly won't work, I'm assuming OP is running on a LAN that NAT'd away from the public internet.

Comment: @DavidG, didn't think about LAN.